# React jest test, unable to test a method 'TypeError: ... is not a function'

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, typeerror

not the full code but similar idea:

implementaion.tsx:

```
export const provider: React.FC<{}> = ({
  children,
}) => {
 const handleDiscard = React.useCallback(() => {
    invokeDiscard();
    ...
  }, [invokeDiscard]);
}
```

implementaion.test.tsx:

```
const actual = require("./implementation");

it("discards") {
  act(() => {actual.handleDiscard()});
  expect(invokeDiscard).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

TypeError: actual.handleDiscardis not a function

why???

Comment: Why did you think it _would_ be? It's not a _property_ of the component function, it's a local variable defined inside (and accessible only within) its body.